# How to delete epic relation link using REST api for greenhopper/JIRA Agile?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile, greenhopper

To add epic relation link I have used this request and body but I want to remove it using rest API.
**/rest/greenhopper/1.0/epics/AG-3/add**

**{"ignoreEpics":true,"issueKeys":["AG-19"]}**

This will add epic link relation for AG-3. AG-19 will be added as a epic relation link to AG-3.

Now for same I want to remove AG-19 from AG-3. From UI also, I have to remove it from AG-19.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found greenhopper API on this link.

https://jira.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/restbrowser#/resource/greenhopper-1-0-epics-remove

(Do not forget to uncheck "show public APIs")

Use this PUT - REST request to remove epic link

```
/rest/greenhopper/1.0/epics/remove
```

Body :

```
{"issueKeys":["HTP-321"]}
```

Here "HTP-321" is the issue id which will be removed from Epic.